# Graphs on $\{0,1\}^n$ based on fixed Hamming distance

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $n$ be a positive integer and consider $\{0,1\}^n$. We define the *Hamming distance* $d_H(x,y)$ of members $x,y\in\{0,1\}^n$ by $$d_H(x,y)=|\big\{i\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}:x(i)\neq y(i)\big\}|.$$

For integers $n>1$ and $k$ with $1<k<n$ let $G_{n,k}$ be the graph defined on the vertex set $\{0,1\}^n$ such that two vertices $x,y$ are connected by an edge if and only if $d_H(x,y) =k$.

**Question.** What is the value of the clique number $\omega(G_{n,k})$ and of the chromatic number $\chi(G_{n,k})$ in terms of $n,k$?

Comment: Not 3. This is the famous result of Payan that cubelike graphs never have chromatic number 3 (or clique number). Your graphs, called “distance graphs” by Payan are special cases of cubelike graphs. Start here https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82733314.pdf for more including a reference to a paper by Dvorak et al.

Comment: Note that for odd $k$ the graph is bipartite (color by parity of the number of $1$'s). For even $k$ quantity $\omega(G_{n,k})-1$ corresponds to the maximal number of $k$-subsets of $[n]$ with pairwise intersections of size $k/2$ (clique containing $(0,0,...)$ looks in such a way).

Comment: That's right, thanks @JosephGordon, I should have restricted the question to even $k$

Comment: The upper bound, I think, is given by Fisher's inequality (which is stated in a various number of ways, see e.g. [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.06286.pdf) for relevant statement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, this is an open problem. In the special case where $n$ is divisible by $4$ and $k=n/2$, the clique number is believed to be $n$ but this is equivalent to the [Hadamard matrix conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix#Hadamard_conjecture). I think that the chromatic number is also unknown in this special case.

Comment: $n$, not $n+1$?

Comment: Why would it be $n+1$?

Comment: Thanks Antoine for making the connection to the Hadamard matrix conjecture! - It would also be nice to know whether at least the clique number and the chromatic number agree, but this may be open as well

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen I found some additionnal information for the chromatic number in this special case. It is known that the chromatic number is $\ge n$ with equality if and only if $n$ is a power of $2$: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0509151.pdf

Comment: @AntoineLabelle well, I expect the equivalence to Hadamard conjecture you mean is the one I described in this [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/374470/graphs-on-0-1-n-based-on-fixed-hamming-distance#comment949217_374470). Then we need to add $1$ to account for all-zeros vector, don't we?

Comment: I don't understand, the all-zeros vector has nothing special since the graph is vertex transitive. Here is how I see the equivalence: replacing $\{0,1\}^n$ by $\{-1,1\}^n$, two vectors are connected by an edge iff they are orthogonal. Now, an Hadamard matrix correspond to a choice of $n$ pairwise orthogonal vectors, i.e. an $n$-clique in the graph. Hence the clique number being $n$ is equivalent to the existence of an Hadamard matrix.

Comment: Thanks  @AntoineLabelle!

Comment: Ah, I somehow thought that Hadamard matrix is required to have the same number of $0$'s and $1$'s in each row (which is quite stupid of me since the rank couldn't be full that way)

Answer (score 2):

Not quite what you're looking for, but appears to be the closest thing in the literature: the clique number for the related case $d_H \le k$ is addressed in Sharifiyazdi's dissertation [The Clique Number of Generalized Hamming Graphs](https://nbn-resolving.org/urn:nbn:de:gbv:104-1087818); references therein also discuss the chromatic number.

Comment: I will wait before accepting the answer for a moment in case somebody finds an exact answer to my question - but your post is already very helpful, thanks a lot! It definitely deserves an upvote